# Estimote beacons Demo Example Apps not working with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, estimote

Getting issues with Estimote Demo examples provided in the latest SDK. After changing to latest Swift 3 syntax it showed several errors. I fixed few but one I cant. I have attached the image below where it shows error **"Type 'BeaconDetailsCloudFactory' does not conform to protocol 'BeaconContentFactory'"**. 
How can I fix the problem?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code inside the BeaconContentFactory file

```
protocol BeaconContentFactory {

func contentForBeaconID(_ beaconID: BeaconID, completion:@escaping (_ content: AnyObject) -> ())

}
```

What was happening is, in the protocol declaration BeaconContentFactory by the sdk providers the completion is not marked @escaping but when you are implementing the protocol your use case requires the completion to be @escaping so just change the protocol declaration to accept @escaping completion and your error should disappear.

Hope this helps

Comment: No Problem.Happy to help.